# Git Clone and also Create multiple folders nested?

Tags: git

Is it possible to do something like this where it makes all the nested folders for you instead of just one?

```
git clone <some repo url> /apps/myapp
```

So it would create both folders apps, my app?

Comment: This seems to work fine when I try it. What version of git are you using?

Comment: latest version, just pulled it down after updating apt-get update.  Then installed it with apt-get

Comment: when I try to clone to /apps/myapp I get "permission denied".  So I assume that's just a crappy error message choice in Git's part that really means in this case "it can't be done that way".  When I try just to /apps it works fine.  Something with the fact that I'm trying to do it to a nested folder and trying to create that folder

Answer (score 0):

There is no git specific feature to do that. You need to,

1. Clone remote repo
2. Create a script and run from root which will move all sub directories recursively to the root directory.
3. For script you can find help [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146634/shell-script-to-move-all-files-from-subfolders-to-parent-folder)
4. Proceed other works ...